# Programmatically layout disappear after onPause and keyboard is shown

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm developing an Android 3.1 Tablet application using `android.support.v4.view.ViewPager`and `android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity`.

The following fragment has been generated **programmatically**:

[image]

Eight EditText rows have been generated programmatically.

If I tap on an EditText I see this:

[image]

When tap on table home button on this screen, and I come back to app I see this:

[image]

But if view is destroyed and then recreated (and I recreate all 8 rows programmatically) all work fine.

What's happening?

Comment: Is the problem that the keyboard appears and the content is resized? Does the content also resize when showing the keyboard before onPause()?

Comment: It works fine before onPause() but when this fragment is shown and I click on tablet home button. When I come back to app and I tap on an EditText I see the second picture.

Comment: So showing the keyboard before onPause() doesn't resize the content and showing the keyboard after onPause() resizes the content?

Comment: I have updated my question with a new picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the problem setting a ScrollView as parent layout.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding this to your Manifest file

```
android:configChanges="screenSize|orientation|keyboardHidden"
```